# How to export a eclipse RCP product with smaller JARs

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am working on an Eclipse RCP project with Luna and the exported product works well. The only problem is that the generated main JAR file is too large(over 30MB). I checked the root of this large size. Some third-party libs, which are all put inside a folder named lib under my project, are also included into this JAR. I also tried to exclude these libs in binary build and then of course the exported product did not work.

I am wondering if there is a way to separate those third-party libs from the main JAR file and the exported product can still use them. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using plug in projects to achieve this.

Probably you will have to create a seperate plugin for the third party libraries and add that as dependency to your plug in.

Most of the time, this is treated as a best practice as you must keep your code away from other libraries or jars.

You may also try to bring a logical grouping by creating "n" number of plug ins for your third party libraries, so that not all the third party lib you use will be kept in the same jar and maintenance will be easy.